# Refresh page after APIQuickAction submission

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm new in Lightning component development, and I'm trying to implement a lightning:datatable with several actions, like add a new line, delete a line, and create new line.

To create a line, I'm using a quick action, and I call it using quickActionAPI :

```
var actionAPI = component.find("quickActionAPI");
var args = { actionName :"Contrat_cadre__c.My_rule"};
var anAction = actionAPI.selectAction(args)
.then(function(result) {
      
})
.catch(function(e) {
    if (e.errors) {
        alert('The action is unavailable');
    }
});
```

It's working as expected but well I need to manually refresh the page to see the new line in my datatable. But I don't know how to catch the subsmission of the quick action.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your "then" block: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your anwser, here is what I tried :

in controller.js :

```
var anAction = actionAPI.selectAction(args)
.then(function() {
    console.log('enter in then');
    helper.refreshPage();
})
```

in helper.js :

```
refreshPage: function (component)
{
    console.log('helper method');
    var action = component.get('c.**myApexController**');
    action.setCallback(component,
        function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log(state);
            if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
                console.log('success');
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        }
    );
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

It seems that the then is fired when the action is invoked, so before the action submission. (the console.log display "enter in then" and "helper method" at this time, the other log does not display at all)